# Insert text in braces with asyncpg

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

I have a follow table:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    datetime varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    param_id int4 NOT NULL,
    raw_data varchar NOT NULL)
```

I'm trying to insert the data with braces with asyncpg:

```
app['bd_conn'] = await asyncpg.create_pool(host=os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
                                           database=os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
                                           user=os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
                                           password=os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
                                           max_size=5,
                                           min_size=1)
db_engine = app['bd_conn']
raw_data = "{H}"
param = "1000"
async with db_engine.acquire() as conn:
    stmt = f"""
            insert into raw_data (param, raw_data)
            values ({param}, {raw_data})
            """
    await conn.fetch(stmt)
```

and because of the braces in raw_data, I get an error

> syntax error at or near "{"

how can I fix this error? It is necessary to pass braces

Comment: Why are you defining `datetime` as `varchar`? This is a bug waiting to show itself, and complicating queries. You should define in as a [proper date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query is vulnerable to SQL injections -> security issue. it's not good to hardcode parameters.
instead, do this:

```
param = 1000  # an integer
raw_data = "{H}"  # a string

stmt = """
       insert into raw_data (param_id, raw_data)
       values ($1, $2)
       """
await conn.execute(stmt, param, raw_data)
```

Comment: @sportul does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `{param}` syntax on your queries, I'd suggest you use [querky](https://github.com/racinette/querky) library.

It allows to do so without SQL injection, and it also conveniently will auto generate models for your queries.

What you would do is:

```
@qrk.query
def insert_data(param, raw_data):
    return f'''
    insert into raw_data (param, raw_data)
    values ({+param}, {+raw_data})
    '''
```

And you can use it by calling:

```
async def test():
    await insert_data(conn, 1, 2)
    await insert_data(conn, param=1, raw_data=2)
```